# How to properly log errors from DocMQ ack.fail("error") call into MongoDB document error field?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, job-scheduling, bullmq

**Problem**

Even after calling `await api.fail("Error: Some Error which needs to be stored in the error field of the doc")`, it's failing the job but not logging the error in the DB.

> However, when the max retries count reached the limit, it call the `api.fail()` and the job is marked as dead with error `({"type":"MaxAttemptsExceededError","name":"Error","message":"Exceeded the maximum number of retries (0) for this job","stack":"Error: Exceeded the maximum number of retries (0) for this job\n    at MongoDriver.dead (D:\\Abhishek Jadhav\\Codes\\Blockchain\\gate\\node_modules\\docmq\\src\\driver\\mongo.ts:487:17)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async D:\\Abhishek Jadhav\\Codes\\Blockchain\\gate\\node_modules\\docmq\\src\\worker.ts:251:11\n    at async D:\\Abhishek Jadhav\\Codes\\Blockchain\\gate\\node_modules\\docmq\\src\\driver\\mongo.ts:307:7\n    at async MongoDriver.transaction (D:\\Abhishek Jadhav\\Codes\\Blockchain\\gate\\node_modules\\docmq\\src\\driver\\mongo.ts:306:5)\n    at async Worker.processOne (D:\\Abhishek Jadhav\\Codes\\Blockchain\\gate\\node_modules\\docmq\\src\\worker.ts:249:9)\n    at async D:\\Abhishek Jadhav\\Codes\\Blockchain\\gate\\node_modules\\docmq\\src\\queue.ts:440:13"})` stored in error field in the DB.

I'm working with MongoDriver option for storing the jobs data.

**Code**

```
async function paymentJobHandler(job: PaymentRequestJob | PaymentLogJob, api: HandlerApi) {
    try {
        ....
        if (isExist) {
            await api.fail(type === "Log" ? "Duplicate: Payment already exists" : "Error: Payment log already exists", { attempt: 1 }); //! This is causing the job to fail, but the error is not getting logged in the database.
            return;
        }
        .....
}

async function queuePayment(data: PaymentRequestJob) {
    await paymentQueue.enqueue({
        ref: data.hash,
        payload: data,
        retries: 0,
    });
}

async function initPaymentJob(driver: MongoDriver) {
    connection = mongoose.connection.db.collection("payment_jobs");
    paymentQueue = new Queue<PaymentRequestJob | PaymentLogJob>(driver, QUEUES.PAYMENTS, { retention: { jobs: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 }, });

    await paymentQueue.ready().catch((err) => {
        console.error("❗ Failed to initialize payment queue", err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

    paymentQueue.process(paymentJobHandler);

    paymentQueue.events.on("ack", (context) => {
        console.log(`  Payment job ${context.ref} acknowledged with payload ${context.payload.hash}`);
    });

    paymentQueue.events.on("fail", (info) => {
        console.error(
            `❗ Payment job ${info.ref} failed with error: ${info.error?.message}`,
        );
    });

    paymentQueue.events.on("dead", (info) => {
        console.error(
            `❗ Payment job ${info.ref} is dead with error: ${info.error?.message}`,
        );
    });

    paymentQueue.events.on("halt", () => {
        console.error("❌ Received HALT from payment queue");
        process.exit(1);
    });
    
    return paymentQueue;
}
```

**Console**

❗ Payment job 0x7a1357d86cc6b3999e failed with error: Error: Payment log already exists

❗ Payment job 0x7a1357d86cc6b3999e is dead with error: Exceeded the maximum number of retries (0) for this job

**Environment**

- OS - Windows 11 Home 22H2 AMD Ryzen 5 4600H
- Node - v18.17.0

**package.json**

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.387.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "docmq": "^0.5.6",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.1",
    "redis": "^4.6.7",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^11.1.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.3.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typechain": "^8.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.16.0 <=18.17.0"
  }
}
```

[DocMQ npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docmq)